# ssis is importing dates from excel sheet incorrectly

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

i have an SSIS package setup to import data from a spreadsheet to my database. when i view the Spreadsheet, the dates are in uk format and all within the 1 month datespan i have specified, but when i import the package a lot of the dates have been converted incorrectly and instead of for example the 2008-02-05 for the 5th of feb i am getting 2008-05-02 for the 2nd of may.

i have set the locale id in the conversion transformation to UK but it still converts incorrectly.

what can i do to stop this happening?

should i use a derived column? surely this shouldn't be needed when using an Excel Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it helps when the data type are setup correctly in the Excel file source module.